# Jenkins extended choice parameter plugin retrieve value from Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Extended Choice Parameter Jenkins plugin. Used the Groovy script provided in the plugin web page, made some changes to it and currently having:

```
import org.boon.Boon;

def jsonEditorOptions = Boon.fromJson(/{
        disable_edit_json: true,
        disable_properties: true,
        no_additional_properties: true,
        disable_collapse: true,
        disable_array_add: true,
        disable_array_delete: true,
        disable_array_reorder: true,
        theme: "bootstrap2",
        iconlib:"fontawesome4",
       "schema":{
             "title": "Environments",
             "type": "array",
             "format":"tabs",
             "items": {
                 "title": "Environment",
                 "headerTemplate": "{{self.name}}",
                 "type": "object",
                 "properties": {
                    "name" : {
                         "title": "Environment",
                         "type": "string",
                         "readOnly": "true",
                         "propertyOrder" : 1

                     },
                     "Properties": {
                         "type": "array",
                         "format": "table",
                         "propertyOrder" : 2,
                         "items": {
                             "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                  "URL" : {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "readOnly": "true",
                                      "propertyOrder" : 1
                                  },
                                  "User" : {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "readOnly": "true",
                                      "propertyOrder" : 2
                                  },
                                  "Password" : {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "propertyOrder" : 3
                                  }
                              }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
       startval: [
  {
    [
      {
        "name": "DEV",
        "Properties": [
          {
            "URL": "host:port1",
            "User": "user1",
                        "Password":""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "TST",
        "Properties": [
          {
            "URL": "host:port2,
            "User": "user2",
                        "Password":""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}

}/);

return jsonEditorOptions;
```

I would like to know:

1) When building, based on a selection/input from the user, let's say: DEV. Then the values associated to DEV would be:
- URL: host:port1
- User: user1
- Password: 123456

How can these values (DEV, host:port1, user1, 123456) be obtained and passed as parameters in the Build steps?

2) Is there a way to mask the value of the field Password when it is being entered by the user?